# css last-child with :not selector

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, css-selectors

I have a dynamic number of `ul.column` and some of these have the `disabled` class. For example:

```
<ul class="column"></ul>
<ul class="column"></ul>
<ul class="column disabled"></ul>
```

I don't know how many I can have, but I want to apply a `border-right` to the last `.column` which **doesn't** also have the `.disabled` class.

I've tried something like:

```
ul:not(.disabled):last-child {border-right:1px solid black}
```

and

```
ul:last-child:not(.disabled) {border-right:1px solid black}
```

but the style always applies to the last element, regardless of the `:not(.disabled)` selector. Is there another way to style the last .`column` that doesn't also have the `.disabled` class?

I'm fine using jQuery, but I don't know how achieve what I want.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This isn't possible with just css selectors. You could use jQuery though.

#### Demo

```js
$('ul:not(.disabled):last').css('border-right', '1px solid black');
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="column">
  <li>test</li>
</ul>
<ul class="column">
  <li>test</li>
</ul>
<ul class="column disabled">
  <li>test</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Replace colon with comma.

Comment: @kazimt9, whoops. ty

Comment: looks right but.. i get this: http://prntscr.com/b3jr8g and http://prntscr.com/b3jstb :/ what could this be?

Comment: @vlrprbttst, this is normal. `border-right: 1px solid black` is called a [**shorthand**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Shorthand_properties), and is actually 3 properties in one line: [border-width](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_border-width.asp), [border-style](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_border-style.asp) and [border-color](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_border-color.asp). jQuery just splits the shorthand into the 3 properties that you see.

Comment: @vlrprbttst, not sure what you're showing in the last picture.

Comment: @Chris as you can see the border is applied to all three columns instead of just the last one and in the second screenshot it is not applied at all

Comment: @vlrprbttst oh I see. Do you have a link to your website? I can have a look.

Comment: @Chris unfortunatly not but i'll accept your answer :)

Comment: @vlrprbttst, thanks. double check your code. I'm not sure why this happens. Probably some css that overwrites it? Test with something more obvious such as `background-color`.

Comment: it's actually a pretty complicated menu with li items moving around as you click, I'm pretty sure it's a timing issue or something. thank you for the help!

Answer (score 0):

You can select the last ul tag in jQuery, check if it is disabled and apply your styling if appropriate as follows:

```
if(!$('ul').last().hasClass('disabled')){
    $('ul').last().css('border-right', '1px solid black');
}
```

Comment: This fails given this scenario: `<ul class="column"></ul><ul class="column disabled"></ul>`.